# Define Jenkins global variable depending on which node

Tags: jenkins, global-variables

I have a need to tell Jenkins where a particular custom tool is installed. But the installation directory will depend on the type of node.
Some of my build agents run on Windows, some on Mac and some on Ubuntu. So the path to the custom tool will vary depending on the operating system.
In windows it will be

```
C:\Program Files\Foo
```

In Mac it will be

```
/Applications/Foo
```

I want to avoid setting this for every job, but I also want to avoid setting three different global environment variables like

```
WIN_PATH_TO_FOO
MAC_PATH_TO_FOO
UBU_PATH_TO_FOO
```

Ideally I'd set a single global

```
PATH_TO_FOO
```

And define three possible values depending on a node label. Then I'd label my nodes accordingly. Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Are you using [tag:jenkins-pipeline] and a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)?

Comment: Not at the moment. I will evolve into pipelines eventually, but for now I'm just trying to fix some existing freestyle jobs.